# nextjs event handlers for onSubmit onClick not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

When using next.js (and therefore also react) the `onSubmit` method of my form is never called. It always does a page reload which can be controlled via the action form attribute.

However, I would prefer the form does not refresh the page. Maybe this behaviour is because of next.js server side rendering?

Here's my markup:

```
<form action="/search" onSubmit={(e) => {
  console.log("I am never called even if the action attribute is removed");
  e.preventDefault();      
  return false;
}}>
  <input name="q"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
  <button type="submit">submit too</button>
</form>
```

Can someone explain this behaviour or tell me how to fix it so it does not do a page reload?

### Edit

Further research found that no event handlers are working in the component, not even `onClick`.

Comment: did you try to return True?

Comment: it never hit that code - the console log never fires

Comment: can you provide a more complete example? I just pasted this code to a next.js app and it works fine.

Comment: thanks for your time - this was a _document.js prob, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the component rendering the broken search component was _document.js and the event handlers for onClick, onSubmit, etc wouldn't work - when I moved the search component so that it was a child of a component in /pages it started working fine ... I had read on the next.js site to be careful what you put in _document.js which gave me the idea to move the code